# typing facebook webpage redirected to https://www.facebook.com/xampp/

Tags: php, xampp

any idea on how can i solve these problem? when i am going to www.facebook.com, i will be redirected to https://www.facebook.com/xampp/ or lets jst say the local xampp in my pc. Please could anyone help me?

here is the contents of my host file

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-1999 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Ive tried deleted the 127.0.0.1 but still i will be redierected to www.facebook.com/xampp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so in your hosts file:

```
66.220.149.11 localhost
69.171.224.11 localhost
69.171.229.11 localhost
```

Where the IP addresses are the current IPs of Facebook at the time of this post...

That is the only type of redirect functionality you can do in the HOSTS file, beyond that a web server normally handles these requests